# Select deselect checkbox on cart page

Tags: wordpress, select, woocommerce, checkbox, cart

I want to add checkbox on cart page so user can select and deselect the products on cart page. A checkbox before each product As you can see on the image[Image showing my query best](https://i.stack.imgur.com/602Wf.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have to copy cart template add it to your theme and insert your checkboxes.